# How do I get Rust to respect memory volatility across OS interrupts?

Tags: c, rust, xilinx, dma

We have a Vivado project that exposes data over DMA(Direct Memory Access). Essentially, when we assert a wire the FPGA pushes data from a DDS into the DMA memory. We have written a test bench in C that seems to show that everything seems to be working:

```
/* Memory Map, write to virtual address*/
void mm_set(volatile unsigned int* dma_virtual_address, int offset, unsigned int value) {
    dma_virtual_address[offset>>2] = value;
}

/* Memory Map, get data from virtual address*/
unsigned int mm_get(volatile unsigned int* dma_virtual_address, int offset) {
    return dma_virtual_address[offset>>2];
}


void memdump_write(void* virtual_address, int byte_count) {
    /* Dumo memory received from S2MM */
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("fifo_data.txt", "w");

    uint32_t *p = virtual_address;
    int offset;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < byte_count/4; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", p[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}


int main() {
    int dh = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC); // Open /dev/mem which represents the whole physical memory
    volatile uint32_t * virtual_address = mmap(NULL, 65535, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, dh, 0x40400000);                          // Memory map AXI Lite register block
    volatile uint32_t * virtual_destination_address = mmap(NULL, (RESERVED_SIZE_MB*1024*1024-1), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, dh, S2MM_ADDRESS);            // Memory map destination address
    volatile uint32_t * virtual_regs_address = mmap(NULL, 65535, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, dh, REGS_ADDRESS);                   // Tlast Handler settings + fifo size

    /* Get Number of elements currently in fifo just as a sanity check */
    uint32_t fifo_count = mm_get(virtual_regs_address, REGS_FIFO_SZ);
    printf("Number of elements currently in Fifo is: %d\n", fifo_count);

    int words = 256;
    int bytes = words * 4;
    uint8_t loop_count = 10;
    
    memset(virtual_destination_address, 0, bytes*loop_count); // Clear the destination memory with 0s to make sure we can see the new data
    mm_set(virtual_regs_address, REGS_ARMED, 0);

    printf("Resetting DMA\n");
    mm_set(virtual_address, S2MM_CONTROL_REGISTER, 4);
    mm_set(virtual_address, MM2S_CONTROL_REGISTER, 4);

    printf("Halting DMA\n");
    mm_set(virtual_address, S2MM_CONTROL_REGISTER, 0);
    mm_set(virtual_address, MM2S_CONTROL_REGISTER, 0);

    /* Setup UIO */
    uint32_t info;  // Contains the interrupt count number
    ssize_t nb;     // Contains the return value for the read() and write() calls
    
    int fd = open("/dev/uio0", O_RDWR);

    /* 0x30 is the address offset
        0x30 is the S2MM Control Register
        https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/pg021_axi_dma/S2MM_DMACR-S2MM-DMA-Control-Register-Offset-30h */
    volatile int *virt_address = mmap(NULL, 0x30, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    uint32_t* total_data = (uint32_t *)malloc(loop_count * words * 4);
    memset(total_data, 0, loop_count * words * 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < loop_count; i++) {
        /* Set xDMA to idle */        
        virt_address[0x30/4] = 0x00001012;

        /* Transfer from Fifo to memory */
        printf("Writing destination address\n");
        mm_set(virtual_address, S2MM_DESTINATION_ADDRESS, S2MM_ADDRESS); // Write destination address
        // mm_set(virtual_address, S2MM_DESTINATION_ADDRESS, S2MM_ADDRESS + (i*bytes)); // Write destination address

        printf("Destination address is: 0x%x\n", S2MM_ADDRESS + (i*bytes));
        dma_s2mm_status(virtual_address);

        printf("Starting S2MM channel with only the DMA transfer interrupt unmasked...\n");
        virt_address[0x30/4] = 0x00001013;
        dma_s2mm_status(virtual_address);

        printf("Writing S2MM transfer length...\n");
        mm_set(virtual_address, S2MM_LENGTH, bytes);
        dma_s2mm_status(virtual_address);

        /* Set tlast handler */
        mm_set(virtual_regs_address, REGS_NUM_ELEMENTS, words);
        mm_set(virtual_regs_address, REGS_ARMED, 0);
        mm_set(virtual_regs_address, REGS_ARMED, 1);
        printf("Waiting for interrupt...\n");

        info = 1; /* Unmask the interrupt by writing 1 to the file descriptor,
                      it becomes masked again after we read it */

        nb = write(fd, &info, sizeof(info));
        if (nb != (ssize_t)sizeof(info)) {
            perror("write");
            close(fd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* Wait for interrupt */
        nb = read(fd, &info, sizeof(info));
        if (nb == (ssize_t)sizeof(info)) {
            printf("Interrupt #%u!\n", info);
        }

        memcpy(&total_data[i*words], (volatile uint32_t *)virtual_destination_address, bytes);
    }
    memdump_write(total_data, (bytes*loop_count));
    free(total_data);
}
```

Setting the virtual address pointers to volatile seems to work and produces a nice sine wave from the DDS:
[Good Sine wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5ata.png)

But translating this code into RUST seems to be more complicated than we thought and we get:

[Bad Sine Wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABu4M.png)

It looks like the parts that are not zero do follow the correct sine wave.

This is the rust code we tried:

```
macro_rules! mem_map {
    ($base:expr, $size:expr, $fd:expr) => {
        libc::mmap(
            std::ptr::null_mut::<libc::c_void>(),
            $size,
            libc::PROT_READ | libc::PROT_WRITE,
            libc::MAP_SHARED,
            $fd,
            $base,
        )
    };
}

macro_rules! mem_set {
    ($mm:expr, $val:expr, $size:expr) => {
        // unsafe { libc::memset($mm as *mut libc::c_void, $val, $size) }
        unsafe { std::ptr::write_bytes($mm, $val, $size) }
    };
}

macro_rules! write {
    ($ptr:expr, $offs:expr, $val:expr) => {
        compiler_fence(Ordering::SeqCst); 
        std::ptr::write_volatile($ptr.add($offs), $val);
        compiler_fence(Ordering::SeqCst); 
        println!("Writing to {:p}: val: {}, got val: {}", $ptr.add($offs), $val, std::ptr::read_volatile($ptr.add($offs)));
        compiler_fence(Ordering::SeqCst); 
    };
}

unsafe fn open_uio() -> (File, *mut u32, *mut c_void) {
    let f = OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .open("/dev/uio0")
        .unwrap();
    
    let mmap = mem_map!(0, 0x30, f.as_raw_fd());
    return (f, mmap as *mut u32, mmap);
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
    let dev_mem = OpenOptions::new().read(true).write(true).open("/dev/mem").unwrap();
    let mut virt_addr_map = mem_map!(0x4040_0000, 65535, dev_mem.as_raw_fd());
    let virt_addr = virt_addr_map as *mut u32;

    // this is the physical address mapped to user space via a memory map
    let mut virt_dest_addr_map = mem_map!(S2MM_ADDRESS as i64, RESERVED_SIZE_MB*1024*1024-1, dev_mem.as_raw_fd());
    let virt_dest_addr = virt_dest_addr_map as *mut u32;

    let mut virt_regs_addr_map = mem_map!(0x4000_0000, 65535, dev_mem.as_raw_fd());
    let virt_regs_addr = virt_regs_addr_map as *mut u32;

    // Get the current number of element for fun
    let fifo_cnt = *virt_regs_addr.add(REGS_FIFO_SZ / 4);
    println!("Number of elements currently in the FIFO is: {}", fifo_cnt);

    // Clear the memory so that we dont confuse ourselves with old/random memory
    // mem_set!(virt_dest_addr, 0, WORDS_PER_LOOP*LOOPS);
    for i in 0..WORDS_PER_LOOP*LOOPS {
        write!(virt_dest_addr, i, 0);
    }
    write!(virt_regs_addr, REGS_ARMED / 4, 0);

    // Reset the dma
    write!(virt_addr, S2MM_CONTROL_REGISTER / 4, 4);
    write!(virt_addr, MM2S_CONTROL_REGISTER / 4, 4);
    

    // Stop the DMA
    write!(virt_addr, S2MM_CONTROL_REGISTER / 4, 0);
    write!(virt_addr, MM2S_CONTROL_REGISTER / 4, 0);

    let r = open_uio();
    let mut _uio_file = r.0;
    let uio_file = _uio_file.as_raw_fd();
    let uio_virt_addr = r.1;
    let _uio_mmap = r.2;

    let mut total_data = Vec::<u32>::with_capacity(LOOPS * WORDS_PER_LOOP);

    for i in 0..LOOPS {
        // std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs_f64(3.0)); // Uncommenting this makes it work!
        // Set xDMA to idle
        let offs = uio_virt_addr.offset(0x30 / 4);
        write!(uio_virt_addr, 0x30 / 4, 0x0000_1012);

        
        /* Transfer from the fifo to memory */ 
        println!("Write destination address");
        // Tell the DMA where to put the data
        println!("Destination address is: {:#X}", S2MM_ADDRESS as u32);
        write!(virt_addr, S2MM_DESTINATION_REGISTER / 4, S2MM_ADDRESS as u32);
        dma_s2mm_status(virt_addr);

        println!("Start S2MM Channel with only the DMA transfer interrupt unmasked");
        write!(uio_virt_addr, 0x30 / 4, 0x0000_1013);
        dma_s2mm_status(virt_addr);

        println!("Writing S2MM transfer length...");
        write!(virt_addr, S2MM_LENGTH / 4, BYTES_PER_LOOP as u32);
        dma_s2mm_status(virt_addr);

        /* Set the tlast handler */
        write!(virt_regs_addr, REGS_NUM_ELEMENTS / 4, WORDS_PER_LOOP as u32);
        write!(virt_regs_addr, REGS_ARMED / 4, 0);
        write!(virt_regs_addr, REGS_ARMED / 4, 1);
        println!("Waiting for interrupt");

        
        let mut info = 1u32;
        compiler_fence(Ordering::SeqCst); 
        let n = libc::write(uio_file, &info as *const u32 as *const libc::c_void, 4);
        if n != 4 {
            panic!("UIO WRITE FAILED with n= {}", n);
        }
        compiler_fence(Ordering::SeqCst); 

        // wait for UIO to give us a hardware interrupt
        println!("Reading UIO file!");
        let n = libc::read(uio_file, &mut info as *mut u32 as *mut libc::c_void, 4);
        if n != 4 {
            panic!("UIO READ FAILED with n = {}", n);
        }
        println!("Interrupt # {:?}!", info);
        compiler_fence(Ordering::SeqCst); 

        for i in 0..WORDS_PER_LOOP {
            compiler_fence(Ordering::SeqCst); 
            total_data.push(std::ptr::read_volatile(virt_dest_addr.add(i)));          
            compiler_fence(Ordering::SeqCst); 
        }
        
    }
    
    let mut f = std::fs::File::create("rust_fifo_data.txt").unwrap();
    let mut s = String::new();
    for i in total_data.iter() {
        s += &format!("{} ", i);
    }
    f.write_all(s.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    }
}
```

I am using rustc 1.73.0-nightly (f3623871c 2023-08-06) so the std::ptr::write_volatile should be stable and working.

As you can see we tried to get as close to the C version as possible. As well as just adding volatile write/read to everything we could think of along with the compiler_fence thing.

From the graph that it produces it looks like there is a race condition between the software and the hardware writing to the physical address. But that shouldn't be possible since we do a volatile write that enables the DMA then we wait for the hardware interrupt before we perform a volatile read.

Anyways, it seems like RUST is not respecting the volatility of the memory operations. I have worked with memory mapped register before in RUST and never had this problem. This is my first venture into interacting with an FPGA via DMA tho.

Comment: Have you considered if it's possible the rust version contains UB? Are there any differences if you compile in debug/release? Also what about trying to make `total_data` volatile too by having it be a `[u32; LOOPS * WORDS_PER_LOOP]` and using volatile operations on it?

Comment: No differences in debug/release I even tried
**cargo rustc -- -Z mir-opt-level=0 --emir mir**
to really get rid of any optimizations that might be weird.
Just tried make total_data into a slice and writing to it with volatile operations and I don't see any change in the result.